# React native Android Theme Background Transparent

Tags: android, react-native, android-theme

I have to do such a thing, yes Android Java, I managed by setting as android:

`theme="@style/AppTheme.AppCompat.Transparent.NoActionBar"`.

But on React Native, doing the same thing I do not get the same result, that is, on React native you do not see anything completely transparent.

Android Java result:
[image]
Theme:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.AppCompat.Transparent.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
            <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
            <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
            <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
            <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        </style>
```